# ¿Como creo un metodo en java para cargar un jcomboBox con JPA?

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, jpa

Estoy intentando realizar un metodo para cargar un bombobox en una aplicación de [java](/questions/tagged/java) desde la base de datos [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) utilizando [jpa](/questions/tagged/jpa).
Utilizo:

- NETBEANS 8.2
- JAVA version "1.8.0_131"
- EclipseLink (JPA 2.1)
- Libreria JDBC

Código del formulario

```
public jfrm_Administrador() {
    initComponents();
    emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("AdministradorRolesPU");
    em = emf.createEntityManager();
    loadComboBox();
}
```

Y el metodo de cargar `jcombobox` que NO funciona

```
public void loadComboBox() {
    //Creamos una Query
    //"Pais.findAll" es una query que fue definida automaticamente gracias al mapeo de la db
    //Luego obtenemos los resultados y los recorremos
    Iterator it = em.createNamedQuery("Tblpermiso.findByDescripcion").getResultList().iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        //Agrego el resultado al Combobox
        this.jComboBox1.addItem(((Tblpermiso)it.next()));
    }
}
```

Como hago el metodo correctamente?

Comment: Me estoy basando en este tutorial: https://estebanfuentealba.wordpress.com/category/java/

Comment: Bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow en español! primero dejame decirte que está muy buena la cantidad de código que pusiste y la descripción del entorno. Podrías agregar detalles sobre los errores que tenés o por qué decís que "NO funciona"? yo no sé nada de java, pero seguro que son datos que les van a servir a los que saben. Gracias! y bienvenid@!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema esta en esta linea

```
      this.jComboBox1.addItem(((Tblpermiso)it.next()));
```

El programa no deberia funcionar ya que no puedes castear un Tblpermiso a un String.

No se exactamente que campos tiene tu tabla pero una forma de corregirlo seria accediendo a los atributos del objeto que va interando para luego concatenarlos y ahora si agregarlos al combobox.

```
while (it.hasNext()) {

    Tblpermiso permiso = it.next();
    jComboBox1.addItem(permiso.getId() + " " + permiso.getNombre());

}
```